# Add an user defined object to an array - and return one of the 2 objects

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I have Four classes `A, B, C and Test`. `Test` is used for testing purposes.

`B` inherits from `A`. and `C` inherits from `A`.

I have a method called `check()` in the `test` class. It should return either `B or C` objects. So i am hoping to add `B and C objects` in an array, and call a random number between 1 and 2. So one of these 2 will be returned. I am not sure how to add B and C to an array. Can someone show me how to do this in Java ?

```
public Test{

public A check(){
  // add new B() and new C() to an array
  // call a random number to return element 1 or 2 in the array so it will either return B or C

  return either B or C;
}


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even better like this:

```
public class Test{
    private static Random r = new Random();
    private static A[] arr = new A[] {
        new B(), 
        new C()
    };
    public static A check(){
        return arr[r.nextInt(arr.length)];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that an enum you have used `private static A[] arr = new A[] {...` ?

Comment: This is staticly initialized array.

Answer (score 1):

The array below can contain any object

```
Object[] objects = new Object[2];
objects[0] = new A();
objects[1] = new B();
```